# parsing bibtex with bison

Tags: parsing, bison, flex-lexer, bibtex

I am a novice. I want to parse bibtex file using flex/bison. A sample
bibtex is:

```
@Book{a1,
author="amook",
Title="ASR",
Publisher="oxf",
Year="2010",
Add="UK",
Edition="1",
}
@Article{a2,
Author="Rudra Banerjee",
Title={FeNiMo},
Publisher={P{\"R}B},
Issue="12",
Page="36690",
Year="2011",
Add="UK",
Edition="1",
}
```

and for parsing this I have written the following code:

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
%}

%{
char yylval;
int YEAR,i;
//char array_author[1000];
%}
%x author
%x title
%x pub
%x year
%%
@                               printf("\nNEWENTRY\n");
[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*            {printf("%s",yytext);
                                        BEGIN(INITIAL);}
author=                         {BEGIN(author);}
<author>\"[a-zA-Z\/.]+\"        {printf("%s",yytext);
                                        BEGIN(INITIAL);}
year=                           {BEGIN(year);}
<year>\"[0-9]+\"                {printf("%s",yytext);
                                        BEGIN(INITIAL);}
title=                          {BEGIN(title);}
<title>\"[a-zA-Z\/.]+\"         {printf("%s",yytext);
                                        BEGIN(INITIAL);}
publisher=                      {BEGIN(pub);}
<pub>\"[a-zA-Z\/.]+\"           {printf("%s",yytext);
                                        BEGIN(INITIAL);}
[a-zA-Z0-9\/.-]+=        printf("ENTRY TYPE ");
\"                      printf("QUOTE ");
\{                      printf("LCB ");
\}                      printf(" RCB");
;                       printf("SEMICOLON ");
\n                      printf("\n");
%%

int main(){
  yylex();
//char array_author[1000];
//printf("%d%s",&i,array_author[i]);
i++;
return 0;
}
```

The problem is that I want to separate key and val in different
variables and store it in some place (may be array).
Can I have some insight?

Comment: possible duplicate of [parse bibtex with flex+bison: revisited](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15305789/parse-bibtex-with-flexbison-revisited)

Answer (score 0):

If I'd seen this question a year ago I would have made a contemporaneous comment so the question could be improved. The code supplied is not a parser, but regular expressions coded for flex only. Scanning an input file for tokens using regular expressions is but a part of building a parser. No grammar or structure for the bibtex file has been defined for bison.

To separate the key and val, if that what was all that was required, could be done much more easily with tools like awk and sed than flex. One thing I'd point out is that the vals always follow an equal sign. Kinda makes them easy to identify without any special syntactic jiggery pokery.

As we have no information as to **why** we need to parse a bibtex file, and the ultimate goal of the exercise its hard to see what would be the best approach.

Edit: This question is a duplicate, as the OP asked it again and it was answered: [parse bibtex with flex+bison: revisited](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15305789/parse-bibtex-with-flexbison-revisited)

Comment: Actually both question is asked by me....(first, i.e. this one had no answer, possibly due to my poor framing of the problem, hence revisited). I can't delete it...since SO don't like deleting an answered question. close vote added.